# filter in ng-options returning full dataset when compared to empty string

Tags: angularjs

I have two linked dropdowns. The second one is supposed to show only a filtered set based on what is selected on the first one. It works fine, but when I choose back the empty option in the first one, the second one is loaded with the full recordset (guess that the empty string is not evaluated):

```
    <select required ng-options = 'convenio.id as convenio.nombre for convenio in convenios' ng-model = 'master.id_convenio'>
        <option value = ''>Seleccione el Convenio</option>
    </select>

    <select required  ng-disabled = "!master.id_convenio" ng-model = 'master.id_categoria' ng-options = 'categoria.id as categoria.nombre for categoria in categorias | filter:{id_convenio:master.id_convenio}:true'>
        <option value = ''>Seleccione la categoría</option>
    </select>
```

What I want is: if master.id_convenio is null or an empty string, the filtered options for the second select should be empty. Not sure if this is a feature, and if so, how can I override it, if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Since you didn't provide any piece of the structure of your `arrays` it's a bit hard to say what's wrong, but I guess you're failing on your filter construction `filter:{id_convenio:master.id_convenio}:true`.</strike>

Here's a simple **demo** which one you can take it as base to correct your:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.countries = [  
       {  
          "id":1,
          "name":"France"
       },
       {  
          "id":2,
          "name":"EUA"
       },
       {  
          "id":3,
          "name":"Italy"
       }
    ];

    $scope.cities = [  
       {  
          "id":4,
          "name":"Nice",
          "countryId":1
       },
       {  
          "id":5,
          "name":"Paris",
          "countryId":1
       },
       {  
          "id":6,
          "name":"New York",
          "countryId":2
       },
       {  
          "id":7,
          "name":"Los Angeles",
          "countryId":2
       },
       {  
          "id":8,
          "name":"Rome",
          "countryId":3
       },
       {  
          "id":9,
          "name":"Milan",
          "countryId":3
       }
    ];
  });
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <select ng-options="country.id as country.name for country in countries" ng-model="countrySelected">
    <option value="">Select country</option>
  </select>
  <span ng-bind="countrySelected"></span>
  <hr>
  <select ng-disabled="!countrySelected" ng-options="city.id as city.name for city in cities | filter: { countryId: countrySelected || -1} : true" ng-model="citySelected">
    <option value="">Select city</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT:**

After much conversation and really know what was wrong I came up to the solution:

```
<select ng-disabled="!countrySelected" ng-options="city.id as city.name for city in cities | filter: { countryId: countrySelected || -1} : true" ng-model="citySelected">
```

**Note:** The `|| -1` inside the filter will *clear* the dependent `<select>`.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Nope, the filter construction is right;  if you don´t use :true at the end of the construction, it performs an unstrict comparation that would result in, let´s say... if city.id is 1 and countryId is 11 would return true because 11 contains 1. Check your own example with changed ids:  http://codepen.io/sergio0983/pen/XKkOOw?editors=1011 Said that, your approach is the same as mine and it works, and I think you pointed me in the correct direction. All the data I use is fetched from a database and injected in a controller, and it comes in text format. Maybe it´s causing this behavior.

Comment: Well, as I said, you didn't provide any structure of your array and didn't say you want the exact match.. by the way, what's wrong with your code then? Since mine works (putting true - if you want the exact match)..

Comment: Not sure... if your guess about the data is correct and I can fix it preprocessing values, I will mark it as solved. Maybe it could be because it is a property of an object (though it doesn´t makes sense, as the scope is also an object, but I´ve seen worse things :P)

Comment: Humm.. but what's the current problem now then?

Comment: Still not working in my project :( The funny thing is that in some forms it is working as expected, so I´m really confused now; I´m gonna try to get a log of the scope resources and edit the question, to see if it can help to diagnose the problem here.

Comment: Well, if you could provide a plnkr/codepen or whatever that really reproduces the issue, I can work on it and try to help..

Comment: I'm looking at it now, tell me what are you expecting it to do and how it is failing, please..

Comment: Yep: choose a value on the first dropdown; it will populate the second one; choose another value in the second one. Now, return the first dropdown to its original state. I would expect the second one to be empty, but it gets disabled, but has all the options.

Comment: Well.. do you want it to be disabled without options?

Comment: exact, if the first dropdown has the empty value selected, all attached dropdowns should be also empty. For some reason, it´s not working. I have seen other examples that set the value to null when the empty valued option is selected. I think that this is what I need, but cannot achieve. This is a plunker I found in another topic: http://plnkr.co/edit/FrBhVlLyHQejFTumrPXT?p=preview when you select the empty value, the attached model receives null as value, in my example, it simply deletes the value. Why could be that?

Comment: well, it's the expected behavior of `ngOptions`, since your ngModel is an `id` and not the whole object... I managed it to work doing a little trick: I added a big number to filter as flag, take a look: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxzvPz?editors=1011

Comment: Still, can´t understand very well how angular handles this situation. Specially, why is not assigning null instead of deleting the property (In the plunkr example, two comments above, in the same situation, it assigns null as prop value). But took me enough time, and well, the 9999999999 doesn´t seems too elegant, but works. I will go for -1 that looks better ^^. Post as an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I would put that logic in  a function inside the controller that fires on ngChange

```
function changeConvenio(id) {
  $scope.master.id_categoria = (id === '' ? 1 : id)
}
```

Html:

```
<select ng-change="changeConvenio(master.id_convenio.id)" [etc...]>
</select>`
```

plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/loZxlp31SfR7SRx9X00O

Comment: I know i can use this workaround or some others, but what I want is to keep it clean using angular filters. If not possible, in the end, I will try to make a custom filter if what I want is not possible, I´m working in a big project, and recently changed to angular, and there are 100s forms that I would had to change if the defaults don´t work.